# Scalar product of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, with lengths $4$ and $3$ respective and the angle between them is $\theta=\pi/4$. I want to find the value of the scalar/dot product of $(\vec{u}-2\vec{v}) \cdot (3\vec{u}+\vec{v}).$ (The basis is an orthonormal one with fixed basis $e_1,e_2.$)

So, I need to find the length of both those factors. I get that

\begin{array}{lcl}
|\vec{w_1}|& = &|\vec{u}-2\vec{v}|=\sqrt{4^2+(2\cdot(-3))^2}=\sqrt{41} \\
|\vec{w_2}|& = &|3\vec{u}+\vec{v}|=\sqrt{(3\cdot4)^2+3^2}=3\sqrt{17} \\
\end{array}

Leaves me with

$$(\vec{u}-2\vec{v}) \cdot (3\vec{u}+\vec{v})=|\vec{w_1}||\vec{w_2}|\cos\theta=3\sqrt{41\cdot17}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{3\sqrt{1394}}{2}.$$

This is nowhere near the correct answer.

Comment: Use $(\vec{u}-2\vec{v}) \cdot (3\vec{u}+\vec{v})=3\vec{u}\cdot \vec{u}-5\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}-2\vec{v}\cdot \vec{v}$.

Comment: Since u and v are not normal to each other,  $(u+v)^2 \ne u^2 + v^2$ etc.

Comment: $$(\vec u-2\vec v)\cdot (3\vec u+\vec v)=3|\vec u|-2|\vec v|-5(\vec u\cdot \vec v)$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: $$3|u|-2|v|-5(u \cdot v) = 3\cdot 4 - 2\cdot 3 - 5(4\cdot 3\cos{\pi/4}) = 6-30\sqrt{2}.$$ The answer is still incorrect.

Comment: @Parseval, oh, it seems I made a typo. It should be $|\vec u|^2$ and $|\vec v|^2$, i.e., the square of their magnitudes.

Comment: @Parseval your mistake was to use $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ also for $w_1$, $w_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\vec{u}-2\vec{v}) \cdot (3\vec{u}+\vec{v})=3|\vec u|^2+\vec u\cdot \vec v-6\vec u\cdot \vec v-2|\vec v|^2=3|\vec u|^2-5\vec u\cdot \vec v-2|\vec v|^2=\\=3\cdot 4^2-5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cos\theta-2\cdot 3^2=30-30 \sqrt{2}$